# cant get correct session id to login to spring security with retrofit

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, session-cookies, retrofit

I'm trying to create automated, end to end, tests to my webapp by making rest calls (using retrofit). our rest calls are protected with spring security, so i have to login first.

To my best understanding, i need to call /j_spring_security_check with user/password, get the returned "Set-cookie" response header and set it as a "Cookie" request header on each rest call i perform.

It seems like my call to spring login "page" is successful as we have implemented an ApplicationListener which logs each successful login attempt,
however, the returned response from the call to j_spring_security_check has a status 200 (should be 302 as the apps redirects after successful login) and the body of the response is the login page itself.

What am i doing wrong?

the login retrofit interface:

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/j_spring_security_check")
Response basicLogin(@Field("user") String user, @Field("password") String pwd);
```

the code to call spring's login:

```
 public static void login(String user, String pwd) {
    PortalLoginService loginService = PortalRestAdapter.getInstance().createLoginService();
    Response response = loginService.basicLogin(user, pwd);
    String setCookieHeader = getSetCookieHeader(response.getHeaders());
    AuthCookieInterceptor.getInstance().setSessionId(setCookieHeader);

}

private static String getSetCookieHeader(List<Header> headers) {
    for (Header header : headers) {
        if (SET_COOKIE_HEADER_NAME.equals(header.getName())) {
            return header.getValue();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

code of AuthCookieInterceptor intercpet method:

```
@Override
public void intercept(RequestFacade requestFacade) {
    if (sessionId != null) {
        requestFacade.addHeader("Cookie", sessionId);
    }

}
```

the rest adapter init:

```
 restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
      .setRequestInterceptor(AuthCookieInterceptor.getInstance())
      .setEndpoint(PORTAL_URL)
      .setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL)
      .build();
```

so basically I'm making a call to login, and setting the returned session id from the login response on each request i make after (using request interceptor)

Thanks a lot

Comment: parameter should be named "username" instead of "user", but it still wont work, i don't now why. the same request by postman works just fine. but using retforfit i get only login page as response instead of http 302 with set-cookie

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the name of the parameters passed, j_spring_security_check is expecting j_username and j_password instead of your

```
Response basicLogin(@Field("user") String user, @Field("password") String pwd);
```

Also, because in the case of this call, the spring framework is returning us a html response (keep in mind that we are doing a POST to servlet), we need to set our converter, so you need to do something like this:

```
SimpleXMLConverter converter = new SimpleXMLConverter();

RestAdapter adapter =  builder.setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).setConverter(converter).build();
```

then a simple call like this one:

```
Response response = LoginClient.getService().login("john", "john1");
```

and from the response object, you can get any information you could need

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this puzzle.
Frist of all to authorize user you need to replace "user" with "username"

```
@FormUrlEncoded
@POST("/login")
Response autorizeMethod(@Field("username") String user, @Field("password") String pwd);
```

then disable auto redirection in retrofit

```
val client=OkHttpClient.Builder().followRedirects(false).build()
Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("http://localhost:8080")
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
        .client(client)
        .build()
```